# Can sender node receive own packet from hub network

Tags: ethernet

I believe that the hubs rebroadcast any bit sent to it to all hosts, including the original sender. I want to receive packet on the sender node. Is it possible in Linux? Is it enough to add:

```
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.rp_filter=0
net.ipv4.conf.eth0.accept_local=1
```

into `sysctl.conf` file?